# Spring bean placed inside application context is not working

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have worked with Spring annotations a bit, but never with spring xml. I have to create an application where all the beans are kept in applciationContext.xml file and not in xxx-dispather.xml. But when i place the beans inside xxx-dispatcher.xml i am able to hit the controller class and everything works fine, But when i place the same beans inside applciationContext.xml it does not work at all. All i get is 404 exception.

Below is my web.xml file

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

 <context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/web-applicationContext.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <listener>
 <listener-class>
  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 </listener-class>
 </listener>
 </web-app>
```

Below is my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping">
    <property name="caseSensitive" value="true" />
    <property name="pathPrefix" value="/customer" />
</bean>




<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Below is my web-applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">


<bean class="com.mkyong.common.controller.WelcomeController" />
<bean class="com.mkyong.common.controller.HelloGuestController" />

</beans>
```

Can anyone please correct me where i have gone wrong.

Comment: What you ask is not possible. Your DispatcherServlet needs its own xml configuration in order to create a `WebApplicationContext` which has special properties that make it aware of its servlet environment.

Comment: But i read that good practice is to keep all your spring configuration in dis[patcher-servlet.xml file and other bean configuration in applciationCOntext.xml file.

Comment: I thought you said you wanted to put everything in applicationContext.xml... ??? Anyway, yes, you should put your web configuration stuff in your dispatcher-servlet.xml and any non-web configurations in your applicationContext.xml.

Comment: How can i achieve the same in the app which i am trying?

Comment: You answered your own question, I believe. And I have too: you have to put your web configurations in your dispatcher-servlet.xml.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package=""/>//the package where your controller are located
```

This will let you just use the controller annotation to locate you controllers.

Comment: I am not supposed to use annotation in my project. It is purely XML based.